# WPF ItemContainerGenerator.Status is NotStarted

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemcontainergenerator

I have a datagrid, which I scroll to top or there arent enough records to be there a scroll, then ItemContainerGenerator.Status is NotStarted. Why is that? How force ItemContainerGenerator.Status to change status to be ready?
Only when I scroll, then ItemContainerGenerator changes a status.

```
private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if ((sender as ItemContainerGenerator).Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainerGenerated) {
        
        if (obj != null) {
            Win.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                Win.SelectedItem = obj;
                Win.ScrollIntoView(obj);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
User can open a few datagrid window. There is a code, which opens DataGrid Window. The bug might be related to ShowAsync

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(OleMenuCmdEventArgs e) 
{
   var record = GetRecord(); //I get a record from listbox to select in Datagrid
   ToolWindowPane win = Package.FindToolWindow(typeOf(Pane), key, false);

   if (win!= null) {
     MyToolWindow.MyDictionary[record.Name].SelectRecord(record.Name);
     return MyToolWindow.ShowAsync(key, false);
   }
  ///... other code, which open window for the first time etc.
}
```

The window class:

```
public MyToolWindow() //constructor
{
  SelectRecord(record);
}

private void SelectRecord(string record) 
{  var obj = LookForRecordToSelect(record);
   datagrid.SelectedItem = obj;
   datagrid.ScrollIntoView(obj);
}
```

It might first selection works, because it's defined in constructor

Comment: As a note, don't use the `as` operator without checking the result for `null`. Since you don't need a dynamic type check here, use an explicit cast: `((ItemContainerGenerator)sender).Status`.

Comment: Not identical but seems like a very similar situation which has a hacky workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391147/wpf-itemcontainergenerator-status-not-started

Comment: What is your goal? The generator is only started when it has to generate containers e.g., when UI virtualization is enabled (which is the case for the DataGrid) and when the content  the user  scrolls to is virtualized. If all items are visible i.e. all fit into the viewport then there are no virtualized items. In general, after item containers have been generated the status is set back to NotStarted until the next generation cycle. You obviously observing the wrong state if this behavior doesn't satisfy your intentions. f you tell us what those goals are we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: @StayOnTarget I tried that, but it's related to comboboxes, mine issue is related to datagrid and I can't put the code in mine method, if ItemContainerGenerator is NotStarted. It won't update

Comment: @BionicCode it makes sense. I have another window, which communicates with DataGrid and data with record name is passed to DataGrid in order to select it in DataGrid. That's why I use ItemContainers to update view and record selection

Comment: Ok I think I understand your idea. The DataGrid exposes `DataGrid.SelectedItem`, `DataGrid.SelectedIndex`, `DataGrid.SelectedItems`, `DataGrid.SelectedCells`, `DataGrid.SelectedValue` properties and a `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event. You can use this API to get the selected item. For example, `SelectedItem` returns the currently selected data item that makes the row. Does this help?

Comment: @BionicCode the record is passed to project with DataGrid, I already have a method, which takes a record, which needs to be selected in DataGrid and I use SelectedItems, but it works just one time. Then another record is passed to Datagrid to be selected, but it won't work. 
That's why I have added ItemContainerGenerator,but like I said it works, when there is enough data in DataGrid to be scroll there :/

Comment: You must fix the SelectedItem issue. It's the most convenient way to select items. Fixing it should be very simple. First you must ensure that the data item you want to select is an item of the ItemsSource. It must be the same instance. If this doesn't help, please edit your question and post a small example that shows exactly how you create the DataGrid with its data and how you select rows. Then I can review it and make suggestions on how to fix your issue. This is very likely a very trivial problem. Don't worry.

Comment: @BionicCode I added more code. The bug might be related to ShowAsync method, that I used. 
I was testing my code-I added timer method to select different rows in datagrid and it worked well, so it might be something with ShowAsync method that opens datagrid

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't posted what I was asking for. Please post a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The current code snippets won't compile right? I need to understand what you are doing. Just create a new project and copy your code and incrementally remove everything that is not required to reproduce the behavior. Those current snippets where the complete relevant context is missing (for example, what is `record` or `LookForRecordToSelect(record)`) didn't help at all.